# How to use mshtml to deal with the link which has JavaScript onclick {return false}

Tags: onclick, href, mshtml

I met a case when I use mshtml to detect the event when click on a htmlelement like a href, I use the code below:

```
DOMEventHandler onclickhandler = new DOMEventHandler(doc,null);

onclickhandler.NewEventHandlers += new DOMEvent(DOMEventMethods._click);

doc.onclick = onclickhandler;

void _click(IHTMLEventObj obj)
{
    MessageBox.Show(obj.srcElement.tagName);
}
```

But if the htmlelement has a JavaScript `onclick={dosomething();return false;}`
then I cannot capture the event.

How do I fix the issue like this?  Or is there any work around?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I choose use mouseup to monitor this kind of event, not a great solution, if you have any other great solution, please let me know, thanks